# ExpandableListView: скрытие названия группы по её открытию

Tags: expandablelistview, android, java

Как перестать отображать заголовок группы в `ExpandableListView`, когда происходит её открытие, и опять отображать, когда группа закрыта.

Есть подобная конструкция

- more...
- объект
- объект
- ...hide

Как скрыть заголовок, когда группа открыта? Перепробовал уже многое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что приходит в голову свой адаптер, при открытии уменьшаем view заголовка и убираем/делаем прозрачным текст, при закрытии возвращаем как было. Возможно есть более изящное решение, но и это должно работать )